# How to filter data from last week in google spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a google spreadsheet on which i have following headers:

[image]

Now i need to filter data according to the Application Date "M". Can anyone help me with the query to get last week data which was added on the sheet.

Basically it should return recent data of past week from the current date.

I'm awful with spreadsheets..:)

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

You could sort the column by clicking the small arrow that appears when you hover over it. Then select "Sort sheet Z-A"